# AVCapturePhotoOutput - settings may not be reused

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am running ios 12 swift 4.2.

I have implemented a basic camera capture session and am clicking images from it. Everything is fine until I am toggling the flash between auto/on/off mode. After I click the first photo and then change the flash mode, the app crashes with error :

```
[AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:] Settings may not be re-used'
```

Following is the camera implementation:

```
var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
var capturePhotoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput!
let capturePhotoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()


var previewView: UIView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    startCameraSession()
    setupCaptureOutput()
}

@objc // Tap on a button to capture
func takePhotoOnTap() {
    guard let capturePhotoOutput = self.capturePhotoOutput else { return }

    capturePhotoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = true
    capturePhotoSettings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
    capturePhotoSettings.flashMode = .auto
    let _ = getSettings(camera: captureDevice!, flashMode: spotmiCameraOptions.flashMode)
    capturePhotoOutput.capturePhoto(with: capturePhotoSettings, delegate: self)
}


    //This is a delegate method from the button
func toggleFlash(mode: FlashMode) {

    switch mode {
    case .auto:
        capturePhotoSettings.flashMode = .auto
    case .enabled:
        capturePhotoSettings.flashMode = .on
    case .disabled:
        capturePhotoSettings.flashMode = .off
    }

}


func setupCaptureOutput() {
    capturePhotoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    capturePhotoOutput.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true
    captureSession.addOutput(capturePhotoOutput)
}

func startCameraSession() {

    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back)

    do {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession.addInput(input)
        videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        videoPreviewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds
        camcontainer.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer)
        captureSession.startRunning()
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


}

func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhoto previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {
    guard error == nil, let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer else {
        print("error capturing photo due to \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        return
    }
    guard let imageData = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewPhotoSampleBuffer) else  { return }

    let capturedImage = UIImage(data: imageData, scale: 1.0)
    if let image = capturedImage {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
    }
}

    func getSettings(camera: AVCaptureDevice, flashMode: FlashMode) -> AVCapturePhotoSettings {
    let settings = capturePhotoSettings

    if camera.hasFlash {
        switch flashMode {
//            case .auto: settings.flashMode = .auto
        case .enabled: settings.flashMode = .on
        case .disabled: settings.flashMode = .off
        default: settings.flashMode = .auto
        }
    }
    return settings
}
```

I am really not getting my head around on how to exactly reuse the `captureSettings` and change it everytime with a different flash mode. I am gone through couple of questions but they are majorly about torch lights. I am looking for the flash .

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AVCapturePhotoSettings` object is unique and cannot be reused, so you need to get new settings every time using this method:

```
func getSettings(camera: AVCaptureDevice, flashMode: CurrentFlashMode) -> AVCapturePhotoSettings {
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()

    if camera.hasFlash {
        switch flashMode {
           case .auto: settings.flashMode = .auto
           case .on: settings.flashMode = .on
           default: settings.flashMode = .off
        }
    }
    return settings
}
```

As you can see, `lockConfiguration` is not needed.

`CurrentFlashMode` is `enum`, which has been created to keep things clear:

enum CurrentFlashMode {
   case off
   case on
   case auto
}

Then simply use it while capturing photo:

```
 @IBAction func captureButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let currentSettings = getSettings(camera: currentCamera, flashMode: currentFlashMode)
        photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: currentSettings, delegate: self)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. If you may see so, thats what I am exactly doing over here.

Comment: create new object of  "AVCapturePhotoSettings()" you are using global variable

Answer (score 0):

quote from `AVCapturePhotoSettings` doc, see the the last important part :

> Summary
>
> > A specification of the features and settings to use for a single photo capture request.
>
> Declaration
>
> > class AVCapturePhotoSettings : NSObject
> >     Discussion
> >
> > To take a photo, you create and configure a AVCapturePhotoSettings object, then pass it to the AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhoto(with:delegate:) method.
> >     A AVCapturePhotoSettings instance can include any combination of settings, regardless of whether that combination is valid for a given capture session. When you initiate a capture by passing a photo settings object to the AVCapturePhotoOutputcapturePhoto(with:delegate:) method, the photo capture output validates your settings to ensure deterministic behavior. For example, the flashMode setting must specify a value that is present in the photo output’s supportedFlashModes array. For detailed validation rules, see each property description below.
>
> Important
>
> > It is illegal to reuse a AVCapturePhotoSettings instance for multiple captures. Calling the capturePhoto(with:delegate:) method throws an exception (invalidArgumentException) if the settings object’s uniqueID value matches that of any previously used settings object.
> >     `To reuse a specific combination of settings, use the init(from:)` initializer to create a new, unique AVCapturePhotoSettings instance from an existing photo settings object.

same problem as you: [this github issue](https://github.com/remirobert/CameraEngine/issues/55)

Comment: Hey, I am aware of that. But there is also where I am confused. I mean how exactly am I supposed to implement it? Should I assign new settings every time? How should I do it?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is happening there. You are generating new settings everytime. If I am correct? Then what is going on with the completionblock

Comment: it's not my code, I think you just use the `AVCapturePhotoSettings.init` and try again,  ignore the block stuff, see if it works for you.